# How to run another C program using execv

Tags: c, process, parallel-processing

I want to run a separate C program as a child process using execv. The below code is not yielding the result I need (write.c is not getting compiled and executed). Not sure what is wrong.

```
int buffered_child;
int native_child = fork();
if(native_child == 0){
  printf("\nnative child\n");
  execv("gcc -o /abc/write.o /abc/write.c; /abc/./write.o",argv);
  exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`execv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) system call needs the path name of the executable in the first argument, and the list of arguments for that function in the second.  It does not search for the command on `$PATH`; for that, you need `execvp()` instead.

To achieve what you want, you'd need code more like:

```
char *argv[] = { "gcc", "-c", "-o", "/abc/write.o", "/abc/write.c", 0 };
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

On closer scrutiny of the original command line, you're creating an executable with the suffix `.o` and then running it.  (That's a weird choice of suffix; most confusing — strongly not recommended.) For that, you need to invoke a shell:

```
char *argv[] = { "sh", "-c", "gcc -o /abc/write.o /abc/write.c; /abc/./write.o", 0 };
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

The `.` in the executed path is unnecessary too.  Or, more simply (without needing to explicitly `fork()`):

```
system("gcc -o /abc/write.o /abc/write.c; /abc/write.o");
```

Or you will need to arrange for the child to fork and the grandchild to run the compiler and then the child can run the program when the grandchild completes; this can be done using `fork()` and one of the `exec*` functions as above.

Answer (score 0):

`execv` does not do PATH interpolation so, in your case, `gcc` would need to be in the same directory as the program you are executing. Try using `execvp`, which will use your current PATH, to look for the executable you are trying to run OR specify the full path to `gcc` in your `execv` call.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Executing-a-File.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the `argv` array that you want to send, and use the full path as the first argument.  For example:

```
char *gcc_argv[] = {"gcc",
                    "-o",
                    "/abc/write.o",
                    "-c",
                    "/abc/write.c",
                    NULL};

execv("/usr/bin/gcc", gcc_argv);
```

Note that the `gcc` entry in `gcc_argv` is the first element of what gets passed to `gcc` as its `argv`.  The first argument to `execv`, however, is the path that's used to invoke it.

Comment: The original command first runs the compiler to create an executable with the `.o` suffix (not recommended), and then runs that executable.  You can't do both with a single command unless you run a shell to handle it.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, I realized this wasn't exactly what OP had, but it was meant to serve as an example of how to invoke `execv`.

Comment: I sympathize — if you note my answer, the first suggested command line is isomorphic with yours (I placed the `-c` option before the `-o` and the output file).  It's as well to explain all the issues — and any changes you make (though I skimped a bit on where and why I added `-c` — but I did point out that ending and executable name with `.o` is unorthodox).